# Using TryParseExact with WindowsForms Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, parsing

I am currently trying to validate a textbox, so only letters (a-Z) can be entered, with the use of TryParseExact.

I have a code to check a time, although could someone demonstrate how this could be done with letters only.

My code is as follows:

```
private void textBox2_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dateEntered;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox2.Text, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateEntered))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to enter valid 24 hour time");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `with letters only`? No numbers? No spaces or punctuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This checks if all characters in a string `s` are a letter:

```
bool result = s.All(ch => char.IsLetter(ch));
```

See also: [Char.IsLetter Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx)

If you want to accept only ASCII letters (i.e. a-z and A-Z):

```
bool result = s.All(ch => (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'));
```

Comment: How could I implement this into my current method?

Comment: @Dan: Are you asking how to combine a boolean expression and `if`?

Comment: @Dan: [if-else (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any try-parse method because checking if a string only contains a-Z chars is not the same as parsing a date or a number.

I think you can use regular expressions to validate the input.