# TextBox validation in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some code that is meant to check a TextBox for certain characters, although for some reason I am having problems with "KeyChar" and "Handled" part of the code:

```
private void textBox5_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string allowedCharacterSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.\b\n";

    if (allowedCharacterSet.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
    {
        if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "."
            && textBox5.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}
```

.............

```
Error   2   'System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyChar' and no extension method 'KeyChar' accepting a first argument of type 'System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\test\Form1.cs    602 48  App
```

Comment: There is no property named KeyChar on type CancelEventArgs.

Comment: why are you asking another question instead of fixing your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414699/c-using-tryparseexact-with-windowsforms-textbox ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using regular expressions instead?

```
private void TextBox5_Validating(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    String AllowedChars = @"^a-zA-Z0-9.$";
    if(Regex.IsMatch(TextBox5.Text, AllowedChars))
    {
         e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
         e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

Or something along these lines....

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, there is no `KeyChar` property in [`CancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx).

Either you have to switch to [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) Event (which has `KeyChar` property in it's event args) of the textbox or consider the string as a whole (rather than one char at a time) in `Validating` Event

Answer (score 0):

Try using `KeyPressEventArgs e` instead of `CancelEventArgs e`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx

Comment: from the definition of the event handler it is apparent that he is using Validating event. Signature must match. He cannot use KeyPressEventArgs there.

Comment: Ofcourse he will have to use a different even handler. something like TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `KeyPress` event instead.  This lets you prevent users from typing in a letter that you don't want (by setting `e.Handled = true`).  You'll still want to use Validating to make sure that they didn't paste some bad data from the clipboard.